# Returning AWS CloudFront geolocation headers from a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, geolocation

We're trying to implement a simple service in AWS where if a users POSTs a given endpoint, a Lambda function is triggered that sends back the caller's geolocation.

I currently have a bare-bones implementation set up where the Lambda is implemented and returns the event that is passed in to it when a POST is made to an endpoint provisioned in API Gateway. I can see in the response that the header `Cloudfront-Viewer-Country` is returned, but I want to make use of the more granular headers [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-cloudfront-headers.html#cloudfront-headers-viewer-location), which aren't appearing in the Lambda's response. Similar to [this question](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-cloudfront-headers.html#cloudfront-headers-viewer-location) but with more granular data.

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is not a normal Lambda, but a Lambda @Edge that you attach to your Cloud Front distribution that can process the request from the client and also intercept the Cloud Front headers (That are more granular) and then give a reponse based on those headers.